# Reading the Windows registry key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" using RegGetValue() returns error code 2

Tags: c++, windows, registry

> Reading the Windows registry key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" using `RegGetValue()` returns error code 2.

I've been sitting for hours debugging this problem, but haven't found a solution.

Here is the code that I use to retrieve the registry value named "test":

```
long result = RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), TEXT("test"), RRF_RT_ANY, &dwType, (PVOID)&buff, &size);
```

Below is a picture that I've added the registry value "test" to the Run key (mentioned above).

The error code I get is 2 which represents an invalid file.

It should be mentioned that the local host is running Windows 10 Pro x64.

What could be the source of this confusion?

[image]

**Modified code:**

I still get the error code 2 after using the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag.

```
RegCreateKeyEx(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        &dwStatus) 

long result = RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, TEXT("test"), RRF_RT_ANY, &dwType, (PVOID)&buff, &size);
```

Comment: How do you get TWO error values from ONE call ?!

Comment: Sorry, I added this confusion. I played around with it - and suddenly got the error code 161.

Comment: It is not very clear what Run registry key you are looking at, there is more than one.  Standard explanation is that your program runs in 32-bit mode so is redirected to the HKLM\Software\Wow6432 view.

Comment: From the code, I look at the Run key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: To be specific, this is the key we are looking at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You are most probably trying to access the 64-bit registry view from a 32-bit application.

> By default, a 32-bit application running on WOW64 accesses the 32-bit
>   registry view and a 64-bit application accesses the 64-bit registry
>   view. The following flags enable 32-bit applications to access
>   redirected keys in the 64-bit registry view and 64-bit applications to
>   access redirected keys in the 32-bit registry view. These flags have
>   no effect on shared registry keys.

**Solution**

You can rebuild your application in x64 mode or you can specify which view of the registry you require.

```
HKEY key;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &key);
long result = RegGetValue(key, nullptr, TEXT("test"), RRF_RT_ANY, &dwType, (PVOID)&buff, &size);
```

For more info: [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So, when I open regedit, I get the x64 view because I'm running Windows 10 x64? How do I see/detect which view I have? Especially, how can I see this from regedit?

Comment: Also, can I specify the view (KEY_WOW64_64KEY) directly in RegGetValue()? The standard (open) keys have view depending on the compilation?

Comment: [How to view the system registry by using 64-bit versions of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305097)

Comment: No you cannot. If you go to the link in my answer it clearly documents which methods support the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag.

Comment: I still get the error code 2 after your modification. I've pasted my code in the question. Can you see any obvious error?

Comment: Are you sure??? It works for me. Make sure that you are checking `result` and not `dwStatus`.

Comment: Mohamad it works now! I don't know what has caused the trouble, but after some modification and cleaning the project it works...
How do you know, you should put NULL (or nullptr) for the subkey? I was wondering whether to put "Run" or "" here, but couldn't find any clue on the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105807/discussion-between-mohamad-elghawi-and-nicolas-lykke-iversen).